# ReadAsStringAsync only returns part of the JSON / BODY

Tags: c#, json, rest, openalpr

I'm trying to setup an integration point to an Automatic License Plate Recognition (ALPR) system. I'm using OpenALPR.

On the local PC there is an agent with a IP camera installed that will read the license plate and send info to the cloud. In the cloud there is a WebHook integration point that will fire each time a license plate is registered.

In the OpenALPR webpage the WebHook documentations says:

`WebHooks send an HTTP POST to your URL every time a plate is received or an alert is triggered. The POST body contains the license plate data.`

I've tested the integration by sending the output to a WebHook test page found on this URL: https://webhook.site/

The result is shown at the end of this post. As can be seen the output is JSON format.

I've done a RESTful service and deployed it in Azure. My problem is that when I read the result, I don't get the full JSON result. Based on the test on the http://webhook.site, I know the WebHook provider (sender) sends all JSON data so I can't figure out why it's not fully received.

If there is a better way to receive the JSON result in my web app I'm happy to hear about it. Below is my take on how to get the job done. Except it does not work ! :-D

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and why only part of the result is read?

This is the part of the code that is called on a HTTP POST to my service.

```
// POST: api/OpenALP
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
{

    var content = Request.Content;

    Request.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync().Wait();
    string jsonContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

EDIT: Don't know if it's important- but the debugging was done by publishing the service as "Debug" and the attaching a debugger. The content shown below was copied out from the break point.

This is what I get in `string jsonContent`

```
" \"color\": [{\"confidence\": 92.68022918701172, \"name\": \"white\"}, {\"confidence\": 2.699702501296997, \"name\": \"silver-gray\"}, {\"confidence\": 1.8385039567947388, \"name\": \"yellow\"}, {\"confidence\": 1.024902582168579, \"name\": \"gold-beige\"}, {\"confidence\": 0.5838126540184021, \"name\": \"green\"}], \"make\": [{\"confidence\": 16.192890167236328, \"name\": \"renault\"}, {\"confidence\": 12.871005058288574, \"name\": \"mercedes-benz\"}, {\"confidence\": 7.908616065979004, \"name\": \"volkswagen\"}, {\"confidence\": 4.901283264160156, \"name\": \"opel\"}, {\"confidence\": 4.583385467529297, \"name\": \"bmw\"}], \"body_type\": [{\"confidence\": 20.72427749633789, \"name\": \"sedan-standard\"}, {\"confidence\": 18.412166595458984, \"name\": \"van-mini\"}, {\"confidence\": 17.614177703857422, \"name\": \"sedan-compact\"}, {\"confidence\": 12.435933113098145, \"name\": \"sedan-wagon\"}, {\"confidence\": 6.872223377227783, \"name\": \"suv-crossover\"}], \"year\": [{\"confidence\": 23.91012191772461, \"name\": \"2005-2009\"}, {\"confidence\": 19.78921890258789, \"name\": \"2000-2004\"}, {\"confidence\": 16.811452865600586, \"name\": \"1995-1999\"}, {\"confidence\": 11.53968620300293, \"name\": \"2010-2014\"}, {\"confidence\": 8.91786003112793, \"name\": \"1985-1989\"}], \"make_model\": [{\"confidence\": 2.5598113536834717, \"name\": \"renault_kangoo\"}, {\"confidence\": 1.564223289489746, \"name\": \"fiat_doblo\"}, {\"confidence\": 1.5174164772033691, \"name\": \"alfa-romeo_147\"}, {\"confidence\": 1.0350353717803955, \"name\": \"citroen_2cv\"}, {\"confidence\": 0.986167311668396, \"name\": \"volkswagen_caddy\"}]}, \"best_uuid\": \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329355349\", \"epoch_end\": 1521329358227, \"best_image_width\": 640, \"data_type\": \"alpr_group\", \"best_image_height\": 480, \"frame_end\": 865634, \"is_parked\": false, \"web_server_config\": {\"agent_label\": \"DESKTOP-B3PMA1C\", \"camera_label\": \"WebCamHKA\"}, \"best_region\": \"eu-dk\", \"uuids\": [\"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329355147\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329355183\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329355248\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329355284\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329355349\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329355386\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329355451\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329355523\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329355558\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329355700\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329355777\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329355815\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329355889\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329356029\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329356274\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329356421\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329356598\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329356738\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329356773\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329356874\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329356909\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329357014\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329357049\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329357148\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329357387\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329357422\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329357567\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329357631\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329357734\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329357870\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329357976\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329358012\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329358048\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329358084\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329358155\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329358191\", \"WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521329358227\"], \"plate_indexes\": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], \"travel_direction\": 255.1732177734375, \"country\": \"eu\", \"best_plate_number\": \"AF22454\", \"best_region_confidence\": 91.45714569091797, \"agent_version\": \"2.5.103\", \"candidates\": [{\"matches_template\": 0, \"plate\": \"AF22454\", \"confidence\": 94.99976348876953}, {\"matches_template\": 0, \"plate\": \"AF2245\", \"confidence\": 69.99081420898438}, {\"matches_template\": 0, \"plate\": \"AF224\", \"confidence\": 68.92207336425781}, {\"matches_template\": 0, \"plate\": \"A22454\", \"confidence\": 65.7693099975586}, {\"matches_template\": 0, \"plate\": \"AY22454\", \"confidence\": 65.72945404052734}, {\"matches_template\": 0, \"plate\": \"AT22454\", \"confidence\": 65.69474029541016}]}"
```

If I look at the output on the WebHook test site (http://webhoot.site) I get this result:

```
{
  "epoch_start": 1521286407536,
  "camera_id": 645063384,
  "frame_start": 109416,
  "agent_uid": "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X",
  "best_confidence": 94.99918365478516,
  "company_id": "d1806fef-5549-4915-86a8-1b1f975e8df9",
  "version": 2,
  "agent_type": "alprd",
  "best_plate": {
    "plate": "AF25463",
    "confidence": 94.99918365478516,
    "region_confidence": 99,
    "vehicle_region": {
      "y": 1,
      "x": 80,
      "height": 479,
      "width": 479
    },
    "region": "eu-dk",
    "plate_index": 0,
    "processing_time_ms": 40.263999938964844,
    "candidates": [
      {
        "matches_template": 0,
        "plate": "AF25463",
        "confidence": 94.99918365478516
      }
    ],
    "coordinates": [
      {
        "y": 248,
        "x": 286
      },
      {
        "y": 251,
        "x": 599
      },
      {
        "y": 318,
        "x": 599
      },
      {
        "y": 314,
        "x": 286
      }
    ],
    "matches_template": 0,
    "requested_topn": 10
  },
  "vehicle": {
    "orientation": [
      {
        "confidence": 48.20035171508789,
        "name": "270"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 26.80327606201172,
        "name": "225"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 10.317419052124023,
        "name": "315"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 5.075159072875977,
        "name": "180"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 4.022528648376465,
        "name": "0"
      }
    ],
    "color": [
      {
        "confidence": 89.68812561035156,
        "name": "blue"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 3.044862747192383,
        "name": "silver-gray"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 2.5986762046813965,
        "name": "white"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 2.5680367946624756,
        "name": "green"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 0.8009989857673645,
        "name": "purple"
      }
    ],
    "make": [
      {
        "confidence": 11.725887298583984,
        "name": "renault"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 10.687095642089844,
        "name": "land-rover"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 9.455676078796387,
        "name": "nissan"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 7.793033123016357,
        "name": "citroen"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 6.8527727127075195,
        "name": "suzuki"
      }
    ],
    "body_type": [
      {
        "confidence": 19.176368713378906,
        "name": "suv-crossover"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 18.331125259399414,
        "name": "suv-standard"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 18.325965881347656,
        "name": "truck-standard"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 11.761542320251465,
        "name": "sedan-wagon"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 10.666444778442383,
        "name": "sedan-compact"
      }
    ],
    "year": [
      {
        "confidence": 19.741708755493164,
        "name": "2005-2009"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 17.747791290283203,
        "name": "2000-2004"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 16.381860733032227,
        "name": "1995-1999"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 13.306379318237305,
        "name": "1985-1989"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 11.591310501098633,
        "name": "1980-1984"
      }
    ],
    "make_model": [
      {
        "confidence": 7.200094223022461,
        "name": "land-rover_defender"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 2.6545894145965576,
        "name": "land-rover_discovery"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 1.7968538999557495,
        "name": "toyota_land-cruiser"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 1.6618626117706299,
        "name": "suzuki_sj-samurai"
      },
      {
        "confidence": 1.4205354452133179,
        "name": "suzuki_vitara"
      }
    ]
  },
  "best_uuid": "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286410173",
  "epoch_end": 1521286411970,
  "best_image_width": 640,
  "data_type": "alpr_group",
  "best_image_height": 480,
  "frame_end": 109536,
  "is_parked": false,
  "web_server_config": {
    "agent_label": "DESKTOP-B3PMA1C",
    "camera_label": "WebCamHKA"
  },
  "best_region": "eu-dk",
  "uuids": [
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286407536",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286407571",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286407607",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286407783",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286407888",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286407991",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286408267",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286408301",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286408335",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286408579",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286408649",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286408860",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286408895",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286408930",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286408964",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286408999",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286409173",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286409278",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286409417",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286409484",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286409651",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286409789",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286409823",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286409999",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286410036",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286410140",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286410173",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286410208",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286410646",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286410751",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286410887",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286410923",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286410957",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286411099",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286411169",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286411204",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286411523",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286411626",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286411694",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286411797",
    "WBFOY6ZDPZR03FGCE5C1S9J5GIH2TFH1H6QPMX7X-645063384-1521286411970"
  ],
  "plate_indexes": [
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  "travel_direction": 18.316375732421875,
  "country": "eu",
  "best_plate_number": "AF25463",
  "best_region_confidence": 97.08333587646484,
  "agent_version": "2.5.103",
  "candidates": [
    {
      "matches_template": 0,
      "plate": "AF25463",
      "confidence": 94.99918365478516
    },
    {
      "matches_template": 0,
      "plate": "AF2546",
      "confidence": 70.50904846191406
    },
    {
      "matches_template": 0,
      "plate": "AF254",
      "confidence": 68.68018341064453
    },
    {
      "matches_template": 0,
      "plate": "AF254AF",
      "confidence": 65.75811767578125
    },
    {
      "matches_template": 0,
      "plate": "A25463",
      "confidence": 65.72001647949219
    },
    {
      "matches_template": 0,
      "plate": "AE25463",
      "confidence": 65.68501281738281
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT:
Ohhh - I can't post an Image. I need at least 10 reputation to post it.
But I can link to it here: https://klitandersen-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/henrik_klit-andersen_com/Ec7DQkhrcFhAgZ6wIF24MbkBgrPcbXsgSa7_msXLZDHXQw?e=cnluHm

Comment: Isn't `value` where your data is? You shouldn't be inspecting `Request.Content` manually inside your controller function. Oh, and try remove the `[FromBody] value` parameter if you are going to read the raw contents of the request yourself.

Comment: I would have thought so too. But value comes in empty! I'll try and remove `[FromBody]` and see what happens. Good point.

Comment: I think if you read the raw content stream, then the initial model binding attempt offsets the content buffer hence you are getting partial string only. It should really be as simple as single line to read raw content  `string postBodyContent = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`, remove that extra `LoadIntoBuffer()` if it still doesn't work, I am sure I have tried it some time ago without issues.

Comment: Ok - I tried to remove the `[FromBody]`. That does not work. If that's removed then the method is not called. So I put it back. I also removed the `LoadIntoBuffer()` but that did not help either. I'll edit my question and add a screen dump with the new code. The screen dump is taken when the break point is hit. So you can see the value of the `Value` parameter and also the `jsonContent` value can be seen.

Comment: If you want just to read a raw json object remove all your useless code (as a side note, the use of `Wait()` is terrible and will lead to deadlocks) and just use this for your model binding: `public ActionResult Post([FromBody] JObject value)`. Now `value` contains your json object (in a simple and dynamically typed structure).

Comment: @FedericoDipuma - Thanks !! That did the trick. Appreciate you took the time to help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that I was on the right track thinking that this is because you have a `[FromBody] string value` parameter in your controller method. That seems to offset the content buffer by 1024 bytes hence why your attempt to read it as a string inside the method body yielded only part of the original request body.

You could try a few things here (at least that's the ones I can think of). Firstly, you should try to remove the parameter from. That would solve this problem right away and you would be able to just read it without any issues as you were trying now with just a single line.

```
        var postBodyString = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Secondly, you could try to read it as a stream and reset the stream's position. If you do go with this option - make sure you use `using` so that everything is disposed once you are done. I know for a fact that this didn't work for me some time ago because the `ReadAsStreamAsync()` in Web Api is a `HttpBufferlessStream` and I think it doesn't support `Seek` operation.

```
        var postStream = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        postStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var postBodyString = new StreamReader(postStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Lastly, you could try and make the parameter `HttpMessageRequest` which you could then read as a string.

```
    [Route("somePost")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult DoSomething(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var str = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return Ok();
    }
```

Hopefully some of these options will be acceptable for you or at least get you going on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Learned quite a bit reading your answers. I didn't have time to test your suggestions because the reply from FredericoDipuma solved my problem. So I'll go with that solution because it's easy and it makes more sense that the value parameter contains the reply the hook is waiting for. But thanks for taking the time !!

Comment: @public-profile no problems, I also learned that you can just use `JToken` instead.